# checksum ICMP echo reply incorrect

Tags: c, sockets, echo, checksum, icmp

I'm trying to solve a problem.

Let explain the question: I have two clients, each behind different nat, that send `ICMP ECHO REQUEST` to server. No problem to do this. Server must be able to receive these `REQUEST`, to store each received `ICMP ID` and to send back custom `ECHO REPLY` with these `ID` in `ICMP` payload to each device.

To make this server builds `IP` and `ICMP` headers. This is the scheme:

```
1) CLIENT A ----ECHO REQUEST----> SERVER 

2) SERVER <----ECHO REQUEST----CLIENT B

3) CLIENT A <----ECHO REPLY---- SERVER ----ECHO REPLY---->CLIENT B
```

Server receives the first echo request from client A, the second from client B and then sends back echo replies but here starts the problem:

In fact the second echo reply arrives good but the first not, wireshark (I use it to sniff packet) gives me incorrect checksum. To send and receive packet I use the same `unsigned char buffer[2000]`, so I think the problem is that in first echo reply I use not-correct buffer to calculate checksum.
This code is used to calculate checksum:

```
struct icmp_header *icmphderp=(struct icmp_header *)(buffer + sizeof(struct iphdr));
//...
icmphderp->checksum = girashort(checksum((unsigned char *)icmphderp, sizeof(struct icmp_header)));
//...
unsigned short checksum(unsigned char * buffer, int len){
   int i;
   unsigned short * word16;
   unsigned long totale;
   word16 = (unsigned short *) buffer;
   totale=0;
   for(i=0;i<len/2;i++){
      totale = totale + girashort(word16[i]);
      if(totale & 0x10000)
         totale = ((totale&0xFFFF) + 1);
      }
   return (unsigned short)(0xFFFF-(unsigned short) totale);
}

unsigned short int girashort(unsigned short int n){
    unsigned char * p;
    unsigned char tmp;
    p = (unsigned char *) &n;
    tmp = p[0];
    p[0] = p[1];
    p[1] = tmp;
    return n;
}
```

I make `memcpy(buf, buffer, 2000)` to store the first received buffer but it seems is not working. Somebody can suggest me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: When you say "...i use the same unsigned char buffer[2000]...",  do you mean you are using similar declarations -- OR that both replies are sharing the same exact buffer? If the later, and your multi-threading, it sounds like you need to lock your buffer to prevent overwriting. Either that, or you need two separate buffers.

Comment: both replies share the same buffer. i ask this question because when server  receive second request, it extracts data to send in first reply. i think i can't lock buffer. So do i need two buffers to solve my problem?

Comment: I think you need re familiarize yourself w/ multi threading and the concept of variable synchronization.  Start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29